# How to determine Windows Server start time using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am looking for a way to find out when the Windows Server was last started using only t-sql commands.

I am trying to stay within the default security configurations (i.e. I don't want to enable xp_cmdshell)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `ms_ticks` column from [`sys.dm_os_sys_info`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175048%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). This is the number of milliseconds since the computer was started.

```
SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, (ms_ticks/1000)*(-1), GETDATE())
    FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info
```

Will get you this information.

Comment: @datagod Thanks for the edit. Good catch and sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

Another way apart from `sys.dm_os_sys_info` is to use

[sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190326.aspx)  --> column **sample_ms** -> Number of milliseconds since the computer was started

```
-- find windows server restart date:

SELECT DATEADD(ms,-sample_ms,GETDATE() )AS StartTime
FROM sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats(1,1);
```

Comment: I just ran this code on my machine, and it gave me a date in the future -- it looks like the `sample_ms` column is negative in the DMV (removing the negative sign gave me the correct answer). I tried 3 other servers and the code works okay as-is. Interesting.

Comment: @JonSeigel Interesting ... I ran it on 5 different servers and I got the same results .. no change in code .. working perfectly fine.

Comment: Ah, I see. The DMV returns an int value. That means the value flips +/- every ~25 days and wraps every ~50. This is a bug in the DMV -- it should return bigint. This hasn't been fixed in 2012 either.

Comment: Bug reported here: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/795556

Comment: @JonSeigel Good stuff. Thanks for looking into.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should be using Powershell instead of T-SQL to build whatever you're using this information for?  See the [SQL Server Powershell Provider on MSDN for more info.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281947.aspx)

You can use SQLPS to do any database queries that you need, while still using PowerShell to access all the WMI objects you could ever need.

Comment: I agree powershell is powerful, but does have a steep learning curve.  Not every server has it installed.  The SQL script I am using is a general health check and runs on version going back as far as SQL2000.  It is nice and simple but provides a ton of information for the DBA.